# Authenticate using a public key

Tags: php, private-key, public-key, libssh2

So in short, I am trying to login to the remote server using PHP's "ssh2_auth_pubkey_file" function. And it never passes authentification. My keys are PuTTYgen generated and I am trying to access them localy but I can not make it work.

I have read multiple StackOverflow articles and other forums but I can not find any solution for this

```
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(
    $conn,
    $sftpUsername,
    'C:/my/path/public_key.pub',
    'C:/my/path/private_key.ppk'
);
```

When I use "ssh2_auth_password" I can connect to server without any problems, but public-private key authentification is giving me a lot problems...

Comment: Are you getting exception on ssh2_auth_pubkey_file or false return value ?
If false is returned, probably keys are wrong.

Comment: I get this msg: Warning: ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for tester using public key: Invalid key data, not base64 encoded in...

Answer (score 0):

I hope it would help someone
as I spent a lot of hours on this myself
eventually what solved for me the problem was doing 2 things

1. Make sure www-data user (in Apache) has read access to both 'id_rsa.pub' and 'id_rsa' files, DON'T put them inside any of the sites HTTP folders.
2. Make sure your private key is in RSA format and that it does't have any password/phrase

Convert "BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY" to "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" by running this

```
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f PRIVATE_KEY
```